# Logging in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a log file while using pyspark, but I am getting the following error message:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

I have added the jar files in my class-path, but I still get this error. Anyway I can sort this out. I even tried to pass the jar file as arguments in driver-class-path, but still I get the same error.